# How to ignore onTap events from parent widgets

Tags: flutter

I wrapped my scaffold with `RawGestureDetector` and it receives all `onTap` events for closing keyboards.

```dart
RawGestureDetector(
      gestures: {
        AllowMultipleGestureRecognizer: GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<
            AllowMultipleGestureRecognizer>(
          () => AllowMultipleGestureRecognizer(),
          (AllowMultipleGestureRecognizer instance) {
            instance.onTap = () {
              FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

              if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
                currentFocus.unfocus();
              }
            };
          },
        )
      },
      child: Scaffold(...
```

When I click text fields the first time it opens the keyboard correctly, but if I touch the text field when the keyboard is open, it closes and opens immediately. So I need to prevent `onTap` events that come from parents and need to allow just child's events.

I tried both AbsorbPointer and IgnorePointer. Both of them ignore all of the `onTap` events. They prevent focusing on the text field and opening the keyboard.

Comment: how about using `GestureDetector`?

Comment: I need to use MultipleGestureDetector or Listener for receiving onTap events. Because I have more than one widget with onTap event in the body. But for text fields, as I said, I need to prevent events from parents.

Comment: I mean I need to receive events from both parent and child except text fields.

Comment: Another option is, can wrap the scaffold with GestureDetector and I can call unfocus method from all onTap methods inside the page. But I'm looking for a better option.